# only admin can login using ejabberd server in ios

Tags: ios, ejabberd

I have setup local xmpp server on my mac using ejabberd. Now I can connect to xmpp server using admin account but can not connect for user. How to solve this issue.

**Log for user**

```
SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to=‘myHostname.com'>
RECV: <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="509633310" from=“myHostname.com" version="1.0" stream1:lang="en"/>
RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/" ver="k0acyvEdZQ7cl5uD5FTPoiOnuaw="/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:socketDidConnect:
iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStreamDidConnect:
SEND: <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-1">biwsbj1raXJpdC52YWdoZWxhLHI9RTZDNDlERUQtOEIxRS00REVCLUI5Q0MtRjY0OEQyMEI3MzNC</auth>
RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cj1FNkM0OURFRC04QjFFLTRERUItQjlDQy1GNjQ4RDIwQjczM0IrT0NNUjN5bm5sSE1kWmQ0SkUzbFlRPT0scz14VzFOb0wxd3dFV2RhRURGR1B1dlVRPT0saT00MDk2</challenge>
SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">Yz1iaXdzLHI9RTZDNDlERUQtOEIxRS00REVCLUI5Q0MtRjY0OEQyMEI3MzNCK09DTVIzeW5ubEhNZFpkNEpFM2xZUT09LHA9WG5PeU4rUjMwL05EV2F0dWsrN3g2MThSRHpBPQ==</response>
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><bad-auth/></failure>
iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:didNotAuthenticate:
```

**Log for Admin**

```
 SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
 SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='myHostname.com'>
 RECV: <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="4147870522" from="myHostname.com" version="1.0" stream1:lang="en"/>
 RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:myHostname.comparams:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/" ver="k0acyvEdZQ7cl5uD5FTPoiOnuaw="/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
 iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStream:socketDidConnect:
 iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStreamDidConnect:
 SEND: <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-1">biwsbj1hZG1pbixyPTg0REY4NzdELTI1Q0QtNDI5RS05QTk5LURGNUE4RTVFQTEyOQ==</auth>
 RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cj04NERGODc3RC0yNUNELTQyOUUtOUE5OS1ERjVBOEU1RUExMjlkSXlidUp1bm45T1pSZmFRbndSRW13PT0scz1zYXV3WFg1MUFoSC9lVUxlaDZXdjdRPT0saT00MDk2</challenge>
 SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">Yz1iaXdzLHI9ODRERjg3N0QtMjVDRC00MjlFLTlBOTktREY1QThFNUVBMTI5ZEl5YnVKdW5uOU9aUmZhUW53UkVtdz09LHA9TGZYTmdJdXZMZmprQW10Tm5KT0FVQmF5MVFVPQ==</response>
 RECV: <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dj1KVE95ZStNVFp2UU1OYlpZZ0JtWnRVa1pEVHM9</success>
 SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='myHostname.com'>
 RECV: <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="3937583598" from="myHostname.com" version="1.0" stream1:lang="en"/>
 RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/" ver="k0acyvEdZQ7cl5uD5FTPoiOnuaw="/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
 SEND: <iq type="set" id="526FD685-D8D6-4A30-BB21-639C46344E0E"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/></iq>
 RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="526FD685-D8D6-4A30-BB21-639C46344E0E" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>admin@myHostname.com/20692733401398173934880752</jid></bind></iq>
 SEND: <iq type="set" id="94B351BD-3BB8-4151-B913-F73CA7638C52"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>
 RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="94B351BD-3BB8-4151-B913-F73CA7638C52"/>
 SEND: <iq type="get" id="728B7EE5-9CDA-4736-B600-BAD72EA42251"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
 SEND: <presence><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="VyOFcFX6+YNmKssVXSBKGFP0BS4="/></presence>
 RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="admin@myHostname.com" to="admin@myHostname.com/20692733401398173934880752" id="728B7EE5-9CDA-4736-B600-BAD72EA42251" type="result"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
 RECV: <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="admin@myHostname.com/20692733401398173934880752" to="admin@myHostname.com/20692733401398173934880752"><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="VyOFcFX6+YNmKssVXSBKGFP0BS4="/></presence>
```

Comment: Have you created extra users besides admin?

Comment: Yes. I solve issue. I change the order of authentication mechanization  type in xmppStrem.m file https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/351